# Not able to find App key and App Secret in Bluemix. Instead of the those, App GUID is available

Tags: android, ibm-cloud

I've created a mobile boiler plate for my android application, but not able to find App key and App Secret in Bluemix. Instead of the those two, App GUID is available. Can any one help me, how to initialize IBMBluemix with APP GUID or provide me with any sample Android application like bluelist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your initial question here is how you should be initializing the Android Client with the new SDK:

```
BMSClient.getInstance().initialize(this, "<APPLICATION_ROUTE>", "<APPLICATION_ID>");
```

If you want to get a feel for the new Bluemix Mobile Services for Android I would start by looking at our [Android HelloWorld sample.](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/mobilefirst/gettingstarted/helloworld_android.html)

You can also look at our Documentation for [Setting up the Android Client SDK.](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/mobilefirst/gettingstarted/android_existingproject.html#gettingstarted)

Here is some more information regarding the new Bluemix Mobile Services:

[Blog Announcement](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/10/05/mobilefirst-services-on-bluemix-now-support-android-and-open-source-sdks/)

[Bluemix Mobile Services solutions page](http://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/bluemix/solutions/mobilefirst/)

[Android Bluemix Mobile Services Docs](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/mobilefirst/gettingstarted/android.html)

Comment: Many more thanks.. Information you have provided is useful. I'm going thru the threads you have provided.

Comment: @Sathiya1992 not a problem. Can you mark this question as answered if it fulfills what you were looking for.