# Cloud app secret disappeared from bluemix?

Tags: android, node.js, google-cloud-messaging, ibm-cloud, dashboard

I can't find Cloud secret app in bluemix dashboard.

I will need cloud secret app to do 2 projects bellow:

```
bluemixpush: function() {
  console.log("device is ready, let's initialize bluemix!");
  var values = {
    applicationId: "",
    applicationSecret: "<INSERT_APPLICATION_SECRET_HERE>",
    applicationRoute: ""
  };
```

http://pt.slideshare.net/ibmdeveloperworks/blue-list-pushandroid

This link below did not answer the main question. My questioning that is:
Where is Cloud app secret ??

[[Not able to find App key and App Secret in Bluemix. Instead of the those, App GUID is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971234/not-able-to-find-app-key-and-app-secret-in-bluemix-instead-of-the-those-app-gu][1])

***And more: I need a tutorial/material about connect Server-Bluemix-Node-RED-JSON with Client-Android 5.0 Lollipop***  ***USING websocket***

Thank's

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm developing a cordova Bluemix push notification application. I'm not able to find "applicationSecret" when I create from the Bluemix dashboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435612/im-developing-a-cordova-bluemix-push-notification-application-im-not-able-to)

Comment: Please see answer in this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435612/im-developing-a-cordova-bluemix-push-notification-application-im-not-able-to

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9gPdWq4OH-XOVlVd3Zxa0IzeDQ/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                   (I have above error when I tried this: http://pt.slideshare.net/ibmdeveloperworks/blue-list-pushandroid

Comment: @NEUBERSOUSA are you still having this issue?

Comment: @NEUBERSOUSA the "Cloud app secret" is the "Application Secret" that the linked question shows. It's in your MAS service dashboard. Using that secret you should be able to initialize bluemix. This also agrees with the error you posted in the comments and in your other SO question. Regards.

Comment: Thank's Jeff Sloyer and Young

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to run (older) BlueMix tutorials with a newer release, see also this SO link:

> [Where is the application secret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35731654)
>
> If you have Mobile Client Access instead of Mobile Application
>   Security then it sounds like you created a MobileFirst Starter
>   Boilerplate (the newest release) rather than a Mobile Cloud
>   Boilerplate (deprecated as of December 15th, 2015).
>
> The new services within the MobileFirst Starter Boilerplate do not use
>   the Application Secret for security or validation. I would recommend
>   you take a look at that linked deprecation announcement and see what
>   all has changed in the move to the new services and what you as a
>   developer would need to do to migrate your preexisting code.