# Where is the application secret?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I can't find my Application Secret key in the Mobile Options tab.

[image]

I went to look into the Mobile Application Security I found out that it is no more. It is replaces by Mobile Client Access. So where is it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Mobile Client Access instead of Mobile Application Security then it sounds like you created a MobileFirst Starter Boilerplate (the newest release) rather than a Mobile Cloud Boilerplate ([deprecated as of December 15th](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/12/15/important-mobile-services-announcement/)).

The new services within the MobileFirst Starter Boilerplate do not use the Application Secret for security or validation. I would recommend you take a look at that linked deprecation announcement and see what all has changed in the move to the new services and what you as a developer would need to do to migrate your preexisting code.

Answer (score 1):

The new service **Mobile Client Access** require only appId and Route. (no app secret)

You can find more information here: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/getting-started.html
In the "**next-step** section" you can find some example that explains how to use the service ( how you can see the application secret is not required).